# Using Linked Server on asp.net mvc 3

Tags: sql-server, oracle, asp.net-mvc-3, linked-server

I have a system that must use two databases: SQL Server and Oracle.

My connectionString is configured to access SQLServer, and it got a Linked Server pointing to the Oracle database.

I am using the Entity Framework, I have a .edmx file that it can map all my entities.

I have to do a query to fetch records from a table that is on Oracle, is
edmx I use for this, or must do in hand? Is there a more elegant way to do this integration? How can i access this table in oracle?

Thank you and need more explanation just ask!

Comment: But are you joining the Oracle table to any of your SQL tables; are they related by some foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

You could add SQL Server Views that retrieve the Oracle data, and let EF work with those Views which it does just fine and you still can leverage the ease of queries that EF provides.